# Should bulk data be included in the graph?

Tags: graph, arangodb

I have been using ArangoDB for a while now for smaller system requirements and love it. We have recently been tasked by a client to analyze a large amount of financial data which is currently housed in SQL but I was hoping to more efficiently query the data in ArangoDB.

One of the more simplistic requirements is to rollup gl entry amounts to determine account totals across their general ledger. There are approximately 2200 accounts in their general ledger with a maximum depth of approximately 10. The number of gl entries is approximately 150 million and I was wondering what the most efficient method of aggregating account totals would be?

I plan on using a graph to manage the account hierarchy/structure but should edges be created for 150 million gl entries or is it more efficient to traverse the inbound relationships and run sub queries on the gl entry collections to calculate total the amounts?

I would normally just run the tests myself but I am struggling with simply loading the data in my local instance of arango and thought I would get some insight while I work at loading the data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What is the benefit you're looking to gain by moving the data into a graph model. If it's to build connections between accounts, customers, GL's, and such, then it might be best to go with a hybrid model.

It's possible to build a hierarchical graph style relationship between your accounts and GL's, but then store your GL entries in a flat document collection.

This way you can use AQL style graph queries to quickly determine relationships between accounts and GLs. If you need to SUM entries in a GL, then you can have queries that identify the GL._id's and then sum the flat collections that have foreign keys that reference the GL._id they are associated with.

By adding indexes on your foreign keys you will speed up queries, and by using Foxx Micro Services you can provide a layer of abstraction between a REST style query and the actual data model you are using.  That way if you find you need to change your database model under the covers, by updating your Foxx MicroServices the consumer doesn't need to be aware of those changes.

I can't answer your question on performance, you'll just need to ensure your hardware is appropriately spec'ed.